# How to extract one phone number from contact.FindContact search results in Bixby Capsule

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

The goal of capsule is to borrow just One contact number from the contact search result of `contactInfos` of type `ContactInfo` and output or add into a structure with other properties.

Getting `ContactNameConcept` input from User via Bixby Voice.

```
text (ContactNameConcept) {
    extends(contact.SearchTerm)
}
```

Using `ContactNameConcept` as input `contactName` to get search results from Contacts.

```
action (FindContactNumber) {
  type (Calculation)
  collect {
    input (contactName) {
      type (ContactNameConcept)
      min (Optional) max (One)
    }

    computed-input (contactInfos) {
      type (contact.ContactInfo)
      min (Optional) max (Many)

      compute {
        intent {
          goal: contact.FindContact
          value: $expr(contactName)
        }
      }
      // What should be done here?
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea is when `contact.FindContact` returns multiple results, only send one to the linked Javascript, developer can do the following

```
    computed-input (contactInfos) {
      type (contact.ContactInfo)
      min (Optional) max (One) // make sure change to max (One)
      default-select {
        with-rule {
          select-first
        }
      }
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: contact.FindContact
          value: $expr(contactName)
        }
      }
    }
```

However, I would say it is also possible to handle all results in Javascript. Consider the case when user search for "John", and there are "John Smith" and "John Doe". Depends on your capsule, it might make sense to handle both in Javascript.